# MySQL transactions deadlocking, but SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS does not show a true deadlock

Tags: mysql, multiprocessing, database-deadlocks

I am having some trouble with 2 processes modifying the same table in a MySQL database. Very occasionally it causes a deadlock and one or other of the processes gets a 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' error.

I found a few answers to why this occurs on stackoverflow, and that has got me some of the way to solving the issue. (Just retry the transaction). I was hoping for a better solution than that so started investigating with SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS.

I have been confused by the output of the STATUS command. From what I can see it does not show a true deadlock. The first transaction is waiting for a row locked buy the second transaction, and the first transaction holds no other locks. The second transaction holds 4 locks, one being the lock required by the first transaction, and is waiting for a 5th lock. There is no mention of the 5th lock being held by any other transaction.

The output relating to the deadlock is:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
130514  8:54:12
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 487333931, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 1007, OS thread id 2990889792 fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 24 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 774102, query id 166772615 localhost 127.0.0.1 nesie updating
DELETE FROM DeviceStatus WHERE serialNo=1234567 AND subDevice=1 AND (parameter='band' OR parameter='arfcn' OR parameter='txPower' OR parameter='lac' OR parameter='cellId' OR parameter='channel' OR parameter='rxReversePower' OR parameter='reverseSnr' OR parameter='reverseGmp' OR parameter='reverseBepm' OR parameter='mobileHeldOn' OR parameter='mobileHeldBand' OR parameter='mobileTxPower' OR parameter='mobileCommandedPower' OR parameter='rxPathLoss' OR parameter='holdState' OR parameter='band' OR parameter='channel' OR parameter='arfcn' OR parameter='rxForwardPower' OR parameter='forwardSnr' OR parameter='forwardGmp' OR parameter='forwardBepm' OR parameter='lac' OR parameter='cellId')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1267 page no 3 n bits 96 index `PRIMARY` of table `nesie`.`DeviceStatus` trx id 0 487333931 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 20 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80151487; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 10; hex 6d6f6e69746f72696e67; asc monitoring;; 3: len 6; hex 00001d0c202a; asc      *;; 4: len 7; hex 00000000342dbd; asc     4- ;; 5: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 0 487333930, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 1007, OS thread id 3063302976 inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 488
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 4
MySQL thread id 774099, query id 166772616 localhost nesie update
REPLACE INTO DeviceStatus VALUES (1381511,1,'scanning',1),(1381511,1,'monitoring',0),(1381511,1,'transmitting',0),(1381511,1,'power',-84),(1381511,1,'band',1),(1381511,1,'uarfcn',10661),(1381511,1,'scramblingCode',377)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1267 page no 3 n bits 96 index `PRIMARY` of table `nesie`.`DeviceStatus` trx id 0 487333930 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 20 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80151487; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 10; hex 6d6f6e69746f72696e67; asc monitoring;; 3: len 6; hex 00001d0c202a; asc      *;; 4: len 7; hex 00000000342dbd; asc     4- ;; 5: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 21 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80151487; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 5; hex 706f776572; asc power;; 3: len 6; hex 00001d0c202a; asc      *;; 4: len 7; hex 00000000342e11; asc     4. ;; 5: len 4; hex 7fffffac; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 22 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80151487; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 8; hex 7363616e6e696e67; asc scanning;; 3: len 6; hex 00001d0c202a; asc      *;; 4: len 7; hex 00000000342d96; asc     4- ;; 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80151487; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 12; hex 7472616e736d697474696e67; asc transmitting;; 3: len 6; hex 00001d0c202a; asc      *;; 4: len 7; hex 00000000342de6; asc     4- ;; 5: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1267 page no 3 n bits 96 index `PRIMARY` of table `nesie`.`DeviceStatus` trx id 0 487333930 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 17 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80151487; asc     ;; 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 2: len 4; hex 62616e64; asc band;; 3: len 6; hex 00001d0c19ff; asc       ;; 4: len 7; hex 000000003428a7; asc     4( ;; 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

My questions are:

Why is this flagged as a deadlock, transaction 1 can be queued until transaction 2 completes as it holds no locks required by transaction 2?

Does any one know if this normal behaviour for MySQL or could it be a bug?

Thanks,

Simon.

Comment: "*Does any one know if this normal behaviour for MySQL or could it be a bug?*" - the two are not mutually exclusive (bugs *are* normal behaviour for MySQL).  :)

Comment: @eggyal I guess the same can be said for a lot of software and APIs. The reason Microsoft release so many new APIs is because fixing the old ones would break all the code that relies on the bugs in them!

Comment: True that.  As for your situation, Peter Zaitsev's article [SHOW INNODB STATUS walk through](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/) (linked from the MySQL manual) states "*Note – Innodb only prints information about few of the locks which transaction is holding. Also only last statement from each transactions is displayed, while locks rows could be locked by one of previous statements. For complex deadlock investigations you might need to look at the log files to find truly conflicting statements.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the new 5.6 variable: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_print_all_deadlocks

This way you'll be able to log all deadlocks, and maybe find which transaction is initiating your deadlock.